# Password Won't Work after Crash

Tags: windows-7, password-recovery

My Win 7 computer locked up, so I shut it down (holding down the power button till it shut off).

Logging back on, I got an error message that it couldn't load my profile (like I'm entering the wrong password).

I logged on the guest account, but can't change anything because it won't accept my password.

Is this a serious problem or do I just need to reset the password with one of the options available on your site?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to log in to your profile with your old profile, it just loads a temporary profile, or does it actually say that your password is incorrect? I would try doing a system restore. It should show up if you type "restore" into the start menu search bar. Look for the most recent restore point, and restore to that. It should fix whatever profile problems you're having, but your profile will be reset to whatever it was at that time. No documents will be lost, but some settings might be.

Comment: OK, let me see if I got this. I can't get past the login screen using my login name. I can get in by logging in as a 'guest'. but can't access files or make any changes. While logged in as a guest, do I restore from there?

Comment: Ohh, I see the dilemma here. No, you won't be able to run a restore from the guest account; it requires an administrator account. You can, however, boot off of the installation DVD, and click on the button to Restore, then do a restore from there.

Comment: Have you tried tapping enter as your password

Answer (score 0):

I'd try enabling the Administrator account (using a tool like [NT Offline Boot Disc](http://www.pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/)), logging in as Administrator, creating a new user profile for yourself, and copying what you can from your old profile.

Answer (score 0):

Or try kon boot cd as long as your windows is not the 64 bits version you can use it:

1. Download it in another machine
2. Burn it
3. Insert it before your computer boots up
4. Change bios so it will boot with it
5. The cd does its magic, you do nothing
6. And, wait for it... you won't need a password to get into your account
   That cd magically eliminates the need for passwords at user login. Once logged in, change the password.

http://www.piotrbania.com/all/kon-boot/